# What is the meaning of 'They are the Decorated Persons'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, vocabulary

An article in New York Times read '***The players involved in the complaint are among the most prominent and decorated female athletes in the world: the co-captains Carli Lloyd and Becky Sauerbrunn, forward Alex Morgan, midfielder Megan Rapinoe and goalkeeper Hope Solo.***' Can anyone please explain the meaning ?

Comment: See [decorate](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/decorate): "4. to give a medal or similar token of honor to"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Decorated** in this sense means that these athletes have won competitions and other events, where they gained medals and similar prizes which in turn  decorate them, though not necessarily literally, that is, they don't have to run around with all their medals around their necks to be considered as decorated athletes.

Another example in the same sense would be some general or war hero who also gained medals and honours (for service to his fatherland or something like this). He or she can also be considered as **decorated**.